# How to get max dates from different columns in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Need some help please.
I have the following table:

| Accountno | TrackNo | PercentInc | CreateDate | Lastdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 396 | 3 | 01/03/2019 | 24/05/2021 |
| 123456 | 516 | 0.9 | 20/01/2020 | 25/06/2020 |
| 123456 | 516 | 3 | 01/07/2013 | 29/10/2021 |
| 123456 | 396 | 1 | 12/12/2018 | 12/05/2018 |
| 123456 | 396 | 2 | 05/09/2019 | 08/11/2019 |
| 123456 | 516 | 0.4 | 08/09/2018 | 30/12/2020 |

I need to show results one row per TrackNo - I have to display the PercentInc where the CreateDate is the latest but show the LastDate for that row with the max (LastDate)
Results:

| Accountno | TrackNo | PercentInc | CreateDate | Lastdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 396 | 2 | 05/09/2019 | 24/05/2021 |
| 123456 | 516 | 0.9 | 20/01/2020 | 29/10/2021 |

Thanks

Comment: One row per TrackNo or one row per Accountno or one row per AccountNo, TrackNo? Overly simplistic sample data will not reveal logic errors in your group definition. Notice how the two responses make different assumptions.

Comment: The answers got me on the correct track and I came up with a solution. Did use max and a subquery. Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to skin a cat with SQL. One approach that I find intuitive:

Get the maximum dates for each TrackNo from a query like this:

```
SELECT TrackNo, MAX(CreateDate) MaxCreateDate, MAX(Lastdate) MaxLastDate 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY TrackNo
```

Then link this to the two records you want with a sub-query and two inner joins:

```
SELECT maxLastDate.Accountno, maxCreateDate.TrackNo, maxCreateDate.PercentInc, maxCreateDate.CreateDate, maxLastDate.Lastdate
FROM (
    SELECT TrackNo, MAX(CreateDate) MaxCreateDate, MAX(Lastdate) MaxLastDate 
    FROM Table 
    GROUP BY TrackNo
) AS maxDates
INNER JOIN Table AS maxCreateDate 
    ON maxCreateDate.TrackNo = maxDates.TrackNo AND maxCreateDate.CreateDate = maxDates.MaxCreateDate
INNER JOIN Table AS maxLastDate 
    ON maxLastDate.TrackNo = maxDates.TrackNo AND maxLastDate.Lastdate = maxDates.MaxLastDate
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select Accountno, TrackNo, PercentInc, CreateDate, max_Lastdate
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by accountno, trackno order by createdate desc) as seqnum,
             max(lastdate) over (partition by accountno, trackno) as max_lastdate
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```